# Why does ChatGPT (sometimes) seem to know about the 2022 Hunga Tonga Hunga Ha'pai eruption if its last knowledge update was in September 2021?

Tags: chatgpt

At some point I messaged ChatGPT this:

> 2022 Hunga Tonga Hunga Ha'pai eruption

And got this response:

> The Hunga Tonga Hunga Ha'pai eruption in 2022 was a significant volcanic event that occurred in the South Pacific. Here are some key details about the eruption:
>
> 1. Location: Hunga Tonga Hunga Ha'pai is a volcanic island located in the Kingdom of Tonga, a Polynesian archipelago in the South Pacific Ocean.
> 2. Eruption Start: The eruption began on January 15, 2022, with a series of explosive volcanic eruptions. The initial eruption sent plumes of ash, steam, and volcanic gases high into the atmosphere.
> 3. Formation of a New Island: One of the remarkable outcomes of this eruption was the creation of a new volcanic island. The volcanic activity resulted in the emergence of a landmass that was not previously present. This new island, unofficially named "Hunga Tonga," was estimated to be about 800 meters long and 350 meters wide.
> 4. Explosive Activity: The eruption was characterized by explosive activity, with volcanic ash and gases being ejected into the atmosphere. The ash plumes reached altitudes of several kilometers, and the eruption was visible from neighboring islands and even from space.
> 5. Impact on Aviation: The volcanic ash from the eruption posed a significant hazard to aviation due to the potential for engine damage caused by ash particles. Consequently, airspace around the eruption site was temporarily closed, and flights in the region were disrupted.
> 6. Tsunami Risk: The eruption also raised concerns about the potential for tsunamis. The explosive nature of the eruption and the collapse of the volcanic cone into the sea generated significant underwater landslides. These landslides could have potentially triggered tsunamis, although no significant tsunamis were reported at the time.
>
> The Hunga Tonga Hunga Ha'pai eruption gained considerable attention due to the creation of a new island and the stunning visuals captured by satellite imagery and photographs. It served as a reminder of the dynamic nature of our planet and the powerful forces at work beneath the Earth's surface.

How does ChatGPT know seemingly so much about an event that took place after September 2021? When asked about many events, ChatGPT will say *'As of my last knowledge update in September 2021'* or similar.

Comment: You understand that the response it provided is fiction right? It resembles facts in tone, but it isn't even close to accurate. It "knows" about these events because it is making stuff up by mashing together older facts. For example, five people died from the January 2022 tsunami and the Hunga Tonga-Hunga Ha’apai island was reduced by the explosion, not created by it. https://thekidshouldseethis.com/post/hunga-tonga-hunga-haapai-the-birth-of-a-new-island ChatGPT is not an encyclopedia. It is a very sophisticated text generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ChatGPT is quite capable of writing fiction.  The response you posted is fairly generic; if I went back in time to 2021 and asked you to write about a hypothetical 2022 eruption of Hunga Tonga-Hunga Ha'apai, you'd probably produce something similar by extrapolating from descriptions of the 2014-2015 eruption.  Note that the details of the eruption either apply to any eruption, or are entirely wrong:

1. The eruption started on December 20, 2021, with January 15 being when it *ended*.
2. The eruption didn't build an island, it *destroyed* an island.  The pre-eruption island was somewhat larger than the stated dimensions.
3. The eruption produced a substantial tsunami that killed five people.

ChatGPT is a *generative* AI: it creates the text that is most likely to follow its prompt.  Any time you see ChatGPT refer to itself, it means you're running into safeguards programmed in after the fact to avoid embarrassing OpenAI, rather than generative output of the AI.

Comment: The January 15 date, even if inaccurate still appears to be non-random. So it probably knows *something* about the event, even if it doesn't have all the facts. I wonder if it's possible that it aggregated this data from other users' questions. Still, it shouldn't talk so confidently as if it knows the facts when it doesn't... Perhaps ChatGPT was not programmed with the modesty to just admit "I don't know".

Comment: @Mentalist, it's not random (nothing from an LLM is), but the source of the date may be unrelated to the actual event.  For example, Llama 2 informs me that Mount Blanc, Mount Qaf, and Mount Unsen all erupted on March 13, 2022, while Mount Aniakchak, Mount Awu, Mount Usu, Mount Everest, Mount Rushmore, and Mount Vernon all erupted in the early part of the year -- I haven't yet found a mountain that it will tell me erupted in June or later.

Comment: @Mentalist, in regards to "I don't know", large-language models are fundamentally incapable of being aware of what they do or do not know -- an LLM works by analyzing its training data for patterns, and constructing the most probable output based on those patterns.  The only way to get an "I don't know" out of one is to give it a list of things that it doesn't know.

Comment: Wow! I guess that makes sense, but also blows my mind a little bit. Only because it's hard to imagine what it would be like to think from a state of not being aware of what I know. For all the ways LLMs appear to be similar to us, there certainly some fundamental differences to remind oneself of.

Comment: The volcano also erupted in January 20**15**, which is probably close enough to Jan 15 for genAI.

Comment: @Mentalist, the best way to think of a LLM is not as a thinking machine, but as a hugely sophisticated pattern-finder.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.wired.com/story/5-updates-gpt-4-turbo-openai-chatgpt-sam-altman/ (published on Nov 7, 2023):

> Say goodbye to the perpetual reminder from ChatGPT that its information cutoff date is restricted to September 2021. “We are just as annoyed as all of you, probably more, that GPT-4’s knowledge about the world ended in 2021,” said Sam Altman, CEO of OpenAI, at the conference. **The new model includes information through April 2023**, so it can answer with more current context for your prompts. Altman expressed his intentions to never let ChatGPT’s info get that dusty again. How this information is obtained remains a [major point of contention](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/09/20/books/authors-openai-lawsuit-chatgpt-copyright.html) for authors and publishers who are unhappy with how their writing is used by OpenAI without consent.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT this and got that response **before** November 7. So there must be some other explanation.

Comment: @user16217248 before that I've read that the cutoff date was January 2022 but I don't know if that is true or if that was announced by OpenAI.